# Building a sequential video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have the following code and I am running this in Chrome where I have enabled auto play with sound. The path loads into the src but the play dosn't work for some reason. I still have the loop to loop through each of the videos once one finishes the next one should start. But maybe one thing at a time, how do I get this video to play?

If anyone knows of a ready built implementation that would be great.

File structure...

```
/player/index.html
/player/media.json
/player/jquery-3.5.0.min.js
/player/media/a.mp4
```

index.html & media.json

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video Player</title>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }
    #video {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%; 
        height:100vh;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video autoplay id="video">
    <source id="source" src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
<script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "media.json")
    .done(function( json ) {
        var id = 0;
        var file ='media/' + json[id].file;
        $('#source').attr('src', file);
        $('#video').trigger('play');
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
    });
    });
</script>
</html>

[
    {"file" : "a.mp4"},
    {"file" : "a.mp4"},
    {"file" : "a.mp4"},
    {"file" : "a.mp4"}
]
```

Comment: Try calling `play` directly on the media element: `$('#video')[0].play()`

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kg6eq7po/1/

clear source in html video tag

```
<video autoplay id="video"></video>
```

then in your success method fill video sources. when u fill add class active  to first one

```
json.forEach((x,index)=>{

    if(index==0){
       $('#video').append('<source class="active" id="source" src="'+x.file+'" type="video/mp4">');
    }
    else{
       $('#video').append('<source id="source" src="'+x.file+'" type="video/mp4">');
    }
})
```

and finally add eventlister which notice if video end

```
var myvid = document.getElementById('video');
myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  var activesource = document.querySelector("#video source.active");
  var nextsource = document.querySelector("#video source.active + source") || document.querySelector("#video source:first-child");

  // deactivate current source, and activate next one
  activesource.className = "";
  nextsource.className = "active";

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = nextsource.src;
  myvid.play();
});
```

Comment: Yes I reloaded the video tag and that worked well, didn't know I just needed to reload the source tag so that will save a bit. When I got it running it moaned I needed interaction so I just put an onclick on the body and that solved it. I enabled it for 127.0.0.1 and tried localhost my fault there but with the click event I don't need to muck with the browser.